# Redirect from example.com/file.php to example.com/file.php?id=1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, webserver

How do I redirect from `example.com/file.php` to `example.com/file.php?id=1` with `.htaccess`?

I want that `.htaccess` adds automatically the `?id=1` to this specific link, but not to other `.php` files, only this specific `file.php`.

Comment: Have you tried any ideas based on the many examples and tutorials online? If you show us what you've got so far, we may be able to show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: i haven't done anything yet. I don't know how to start

Comment: You'll end up in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^file\.php$ $0?id=1 [L,NC,QSA,R=302]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)